# URL redirect when accessing domain

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module, windows-server-2019

is the first time I'm using IIS (Windows Server 2019) and I'm looking for a configuration to be able to redirect clients from http://mysiteExample.org/ to http://mysiteExample.org/embed.html?key=val. I considered that URL Rewrite Module could help me to achieve this (as is not necessary for the clients to see the new URL they'll be redirected to). I made the configuration as [shown in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9oJv.png), where I set '^$' as a pattern to specify this should apply for cases where no URL string is provided.

Could somebody with more experience advise me on how to achieve what specified above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem here? Learn how to use FRT to debug your rewrite rules, and then you can help yourself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @LexLi, following FRT I finally managed to find the issue.

Comment: You might post your own answer and accept it. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work changing the action type from 'Rewrite' to 'Redirect'.